# vue router showing blank page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently building a web application using vue.js for my frontend, during the implementation of my router I don't see any error, but still is not showing anything in any page, clearly I've ensured already that everything is running and without errors, here's what I have:

`App.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

`Router.js`

```
import Vue    from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home    from './components/Home'
import Table   from './components/Table'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/table',
            component: Table
        },
    ],
    linkActiveClass: "active",
    mode: "hash"
})
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
})
```

And as an example `Home.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-3">
      <h1>You're looking at your home</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
      return {}
    }
};
</script>
```

Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have should work. Just to rule this one out: are you sure your development server is still up? If it is, please create a [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar which reproduces your error. It's possible your app doesn't render from a completely different reason than router, which seems configured just fine. Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, reproduced my project at codesandbox which is showing blank too, also there are not console errors.

Comment: Interesting. Do you expect anyone to look at your sandbox and figure out what's going on without you sharing that link?

Comment: Sorry, here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-ives-smq5t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Looks [perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4mVN.png). What are you expecting? That's the contents of `Home.vue` in your codesandbox (check `components` folder).

Comment: And the router [works quite well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55OWv.png), too.

Comment: Yu're right, thought I had a diferent message on home and shown was default vue titles, weird thing that my local doesn't look the same

Comment: Check for any differences between your local and the sandbox. I'd look at the contents of `index.html` in `/public` first. That's the template used to render the app by development server (`npm run serve` command). Does it have an `<div id="app"></div>` in your project? (that's what `new Vue({ el: "#app", ...})` is looking for. If it doesn't find it in DOM, it doesn't mount the app

Comment: Reviewed everything twice, checked for errors, created a new project copying all sandbox code but still nothing works, I'll reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sandbox code you doesn't have the same code shown in your answer, so that's the reason to not see the same, but everything is working fine.

If you want to see the table page in your sandbox add this `li` tag inside one of the `ul` tags in your sandbox home component:

```
<li>
  <a
    href="#/table"
  >table</a>
</li>
```

or

```
<router-link to="table">Go to Table</router-link>
```

In your Table.vue component add to go back

```
<router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
```